# How to make responsive for Box={3}

Tags: reactjs

I have `<Box p={3}>` but I want p={2} when it come to mobile. I can use css to do that but I would like to know if any way else to config it by MUI?

Comment: What are you using to know whether your app is on mobile on not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-device-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect) to determine the device being used,

First install the library, `npm install react-device-detect --save`

After installing import the react-device-detect library and use in your  component,

```
import { isBrowser } from 'react-device-detect';

<Box p={isBrowser ? 3 : 2}/>
```

Comment: thanks so much, it's what I need.

Comment: You're welcome! :) happy coding